# Having an error when saving imageview width and height must be > 0

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to save imageView into sd card but I get the following exception (some times not always) when I try to get bitmap from imageView. Can somebody please help me? Thanks in advance

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:922)
```

---

```
public static class SaveImageToSD extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context context;
    ImageView mImageView;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public SaveImageToSD(Context context, ImageView iv, String name) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mImageView = iv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait), true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... x) {

        File projectFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + Settings.projectFolder + File.separator);
        boolean folderCreateSuccess = true;
        if (!projectFolder.exists()) {
            folderCreateSuccess = projectFolder.mkdir();
        }
        if (folderCreateSuccess) {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            // Exception in if statement
            if (mImageView.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            } else {
                Drawable d = mImageView.getDrawable();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                d.draw(canvas);
            }
            File image = new File(projectFolder, "GE_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            boolean success = false;

            // Encode the file as a PNG image.
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "description");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, image.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, image.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
                values.put("_data", image.getAbsolutePath());

                ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                success = true;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (success) {
                ((ActionBarActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.image_successfully_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                ((ActionBarActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.image_successfully_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        } else {
            Log.i("Create Folder", "Error during create folder");
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

to set image I use following code, I'm using transparentDrawable because of Picasso wrap content problem

```
transparentDrawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
Picasso.with(mContext).load(((FBPhotoCard) mImageCards.get(position)).getThumbnail()).placeholder(transparentDrawable).noFade().into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?  Drawable d = mImageView.getDrawable();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                d.draw(canvas);

Comment: btw another question ... what do you mean by sometimes happens.. is it for different images.. or for the same image it sometimes happens ?

Comment: I tested the application using 3 devices, It works well but it happened on users devices I can't repeat it to see what the problem on my test devices

Answer (score 0):

I think the exception is of because `d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()` at line `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`

According to [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicWidth()) `drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()` Return the intrinsic width of the underlying drawable object. Returns -1 if it has no intrinsic width, such as with a solid color. So make sure to pass values greater than 1 to `Bitmap.createBitmap()` method

Comment: I use the following code to set imageView, I use transparentDrawable to solve Picasso wrap content problem

transparentDrawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000));
Picasso.with(mContext).load(((FBPhotoCard) mImageCards.get(position)).getThumbnail()).placeholder(transparentDrawable).noFade().into(holder.imageView);

Answer (score 0):

This error you are getting because `d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()` returning 0 try to put some constant value and then check like 100.